# Flutter Retrieved data in SQFlite database gets loaded but not displayed

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I'm trying to display the username from the database in a Text. the data gets loaded and printed successfully as below. it does not give me an error or anything just plank text. I'm using sqflite as the local database.

`[{id: 1, username: sara, email: sara3@gmail.com, weight: 180, height: 180, gender: Female, age: 2023-12-12T00:00:00.000}]`

but I can't get it to display on the screen

Here's my code where I want to display the username

```
DatabaseHelper? databaseHelper;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

      FutureBuilder(
                      future: databaseHelper?.getDatabaseModelWithId(),
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        final user = snapshot.data;
                        if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
                          return Row(
                            children: [
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    user['username'],
                                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                      textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          letterSpacing: .5,
                                          fontSize: 32),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    height: 5,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    now,
                                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                      textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white38,
                                          letterSpacing: .5,
                                          fontSize: 15),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          );
                        } else {
                          return Text("Error");
                        }
                      },
                    ),
```

DatabaseHelper:

```
  Future<UserModel?> getDatabaseModelWithId() async {
final db = await getDB();
var response = await db.query(
  'User',
  where: 'id = 1',
);
print(response);
return response.isNotEmpty ? UserModel.fromMap(response.first) : null;}
```

UserModel:

```
  final String? id;
  final String? userName;
  final String? email;
  final String? age;
  final int? weight;
  final int? height;
  final String? gender;

  const UserModel({
    this.id,
    this.userName,
    this.email,
    this.age,
    this.weight,
    this.height,
    this.gender,
  });

  factory UserModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel(
        id: json['id'] as String,
        userName: json['userName'] as String?,
        email: json['email'] as String?,
        age: json['age'] as String?,
        weight: json['weight'] as int?,
        height: json['height'] as int?,
        gender: json['gender'] as String?,
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => <String, dynamic>{
        'id': id,
        'userName': userName,
        'email': email,
        'age': age,
        'weight': weight,
        'height': height,
        'gender': gender,
      };
}
```

Comment: In the example json, `username` is with lowercase `n`, while in the UserModel it is not, isn't that the problem?

Comment: @Dávid Laczkó i fixed that still no result

Comment: its a JSONArray . try user[0].['username']; May help . And also change the parameter of Model from userName to username .

Comment: @Rahul Kushwaha ig its an issue with UserModel.fromMap. i tried to print check but its not printing and the snapshot.error says (Error: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast) any idea?

Comment: (Error: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast ). This error -means You are String to Int . Check the parameter carefully .

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you are trying to display the data before it is loaded from the database. Make sure that you have the correct permissions to access the database and that the data is actually being uploaded.

Also make sure that your `getDatabaseModelWithId` method returns the correct data type. In your case, this is a `UserModel`.

Try to change your code as follows:

```
FutureBuilder(   
future: databaseHelper?.getDatabaseModelWithId(),   builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<UserModel?> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
        final user = snapshot.data!;
        return Row(
          children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  user.username,
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      letterSpacing: .5,
                      fontSize: 32
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                Text(
                  now,
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white38,
                      letterSpacing: .5,
                      fontSize: 15
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        );
      } else {
        return Text("Error");
      }
    } else {
      return CircularProgressIndicator(); // Show loading indicator
    }   
}, 
)
```

Comment: I tried to print the snapshot error and i got this (Error: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast) any idea?

Comment: Could you please share text error with error string?